# Stop setInterval in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am decreasing time using setInterval in react native. I want to stop timer after 2 seconds but it's not stopping.
Please help me with clearInterval.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [otpTimer, setOtpTimer] = useState(120);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setOtpTimer((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{otpTimer}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Hopei t helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I am decreasing number not increasing and atfer 2 minues it will be clear it's just like OTP.

Comment: add a setTimeout and after 2 minutes call my clearInterval(interval);